# Boxplot for one element instead of all of them

Tags: r

```
install.packages("HSAUR")
data("Forbes2000", package="HSAUR")  
boxplot((log(Forbes2000$marketvalue)~Forbes2000$country))
```

I get the boxplot for each and every country, is there a way for me to get it for only one desired country? For example the united states (which is indexed 1 in forbes2000$country) .[Here's how the code runs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea3fe.png) . I want the highlighted part.
I tried doing this :

```
boxplot((log(Forbes2000$marketvalue[1])~Forbes2000$country[1]))
```

but it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need the double parentheses.

Second, try running `Forbes2000$marketvalue[1]`. You'll see that it returns the first value of the column `marketvalue`. So that's not what you want either.

What you need to do is select only those rows with the country of interest. One way to do that is `subset`. It may also be clearer to use the formula method for `boxplot`, so you can specify the `data`.

```
boxplot(log(marketvalue) ~ country, data = subset(Forbes2000, country == "United States"))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, I get the graph I want but the x axis is filled with all countries, [here's how it looks](https://i.imgur.com/uzhrIr7.png)

I figured I can use the xlim argument : 

`boxplot(log(marketvalue) ~ country, data = subset(Forbes2000, country == "United states"),xlim=subset(Forbes2000, country == "United states"))`

I also tried `boxplot(log(marketvalue) ~ country, data = subset(Forbes2000, country == "United states"),xlim=Forbes2000$country[1])` both don't work.

Comment: Just `xlim = "United States"` is easiest, I would think.

Comment: I tried that too and it errors out `invalid 'xlim' value`. did it plot for you that way automatically?

Comment: Oops - apologies, that was a typo. Should be `xlab = "United States"`.

Comment: [ah I did xlab, it just replaces "country" with "United States"](https://i.imgur.com/KqyC0be.png)